# How can I choose which version of a partcular system class to use?

Tags: c#, .net

Recently I learned that while the NET 2.0 version of `StringBuilder` was optimized for `ToString()` the NET 4.0 version is optimized for `Append()`. And this got me wondering — can I choose which version of system class to use in each case?

(This question isn't about `StringBuilder`, but about any system class. `StringBuilder` is only an example.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this would generate namespace conflicts, but I don't know and it's an interesting question.  The mono / Unity3d aspect isn't really relevant, though, so I edited it out.  If you want a specifically Mono-based answer, feel free to revert my edit or make a new one to indicate that.

Comment: but, would you really want to? What tangible benefits do you get from using the .Net 2.0 version of `StringBuilder` or any other class. Have you identified a measureable improvment for your situation? How does this benefit balance against the cost of side by side running and any unforseen defecits in the older code?

Comment: Typically the latest version of the Framework will have the best performance.  Even if an other version might have an edge this sound like premature optimization.  If the the current version is causing performance problems then evaluate your options.

Comment: @Jodrell I don't really need it right now, I'm asking this question strictly out of curiosity.

Comment: I must admit, I'm interested in the answers and the idea.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.

Generally system classes (or any third party library) may cooperate behind the scenes, using private data to communicate (that is those items marked private or internal).

If you try to use the wrong versions together, they may not find the private data they expect, and unexpected behaviour will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                           publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                           culture="en-us" />
         <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in application, publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                          newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="mySecondAssembly"
                           publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                           culture="en-us" />
          <!-- Publisher policy can be set only in the application configuration file. -->
          <publisherPolicy apply="no">
       </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```